# call async await from normal method

Tags: c#, async-await

i tried to call async from normal sync method.

below are my example.

```
    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await SetRowsToList(ds_list.Tables[0].Rows));
    Task.WaitAll(taskA);
lst_schemabase.count(); // should be 4k records. List<myClassFile> lst_schemabase


protected async Task<UInt32> SetRowsToList(DataRowCollection Rows)
        {
            List<Task<UInt32>> lst_tasks = new List<Task<uint>>();

            foreach (DataRow row in Rows)
            {
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    lst_schemabase.Add(SetDBfromRow(row));
                    return (UInt32)0;
                });
                lst_tasks.Add(task);
            }


            await Task.WhenAll(lst_tasks);
            return 0;

        }
```

but, my lst_schemabase, sometimes retrieve 20 records, sometimes 800++ records. not able to get the correct record/ wait till all completed. what i have done wrong??

Comment: That is called "sync over async", and is often an anti-pattern; worse, that could actually deadlock on a lot of frameworks (including asp.net), since you are performing an active wait on something that does an `await` but which captures the sync-context. That is simply not a good idea.

Comment: Well, let's start with the fact that `List<T>` isn't thread-safe... have you considered using a concurrent collection? (As Marc says, doing this is basically not a good idea anyway...)

Comment: It actually looks like all of that could be replaced with a single `Parallel.ForEach`, retaining most of your intent, but without the pain...

Comment: thanks for all, i think is not a method as well, because my grid sorting to list out in html also will base on the List<object> sorting.  in that case, async will add the records without in seq. therefore, i think i hav drop this idea. thanks for all of u reply...